# Getting "TypeError: unhashable type" when using urllib2.urlopen

Tags: python, json, api, urllib2

```
headers = {"X-RJM-API-Key": "my API key here"}
url = "the url"
response = urllib2.Request(url, headers)
re = urllib2.urlopen(response)
```

The above should "Returns a JSON-encoded list of charts that are available for export."

but instead I'm just getting the TypeError: unhashable type

any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you getting that error?  can you post the full traceback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument to `Request()` is `data`, not `headers`. Use an explicit keyword parameter:

```
response = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Ran into another bug though. Now I'm getting  "httplib.BadStatusLine: ''" I'll do some reading about it,but if you happen to have quick insight, would appreciate that too :)

Comment: @user3546020: that usually means the server closed the connection without a response. You got an empty status line instead of `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` or similar.